# Getting Error on Clicking Catalog -> Manage Categories in Magento Admin Panel

Tags: php, magento, core-data

I am getting following error when I click on Catalog -> Manage Categories in Magento Admin Panel

There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

> Error log record number: 481584870868

I saw in var/report in file 481584870868 for message...

following is the content of the file:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:100:"Source model "prima/system_config_source_ppagetmp" not found for attribute "ppage_template_override"";i:1;s:4101:"#0 /home/harmonic/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(387): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model "p...')

 #1 /home/harmonic/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(201): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()

 #2 /home/harmonic/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tab/Attributes.php(113): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset))

 #3 /home/harmonic/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(144): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Attributes->_prepareForm()

 #4 /home/harmonic/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_beforeToHtml()

 #5 /home/harmonic/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tabs.php(140): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()

 #6 /home/harmonic/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs->_prepareLayout()

 #7 /home/harmonic/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))

 #8 /home/harmonic/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Edit/Form.php(55): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'tabs')

 #9 /home/harmonic/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Edit_Form->_prepareLayout()

 #10 /home/harmonic/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))

 #11 /home/harmonic/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php(93): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...')

 #12 /home/harmonic/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container->_prepareLayout()

 #13 /home/harmonic/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))

  #14 /home/harmonic/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')

   #15 /home/harmonic/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')

  #16 /home/harmonic/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))

  #17 /home/harmonic/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))

  #18 /home/harmonic/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()

  #19 /home/harmonic/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()

  #20 /home/harmonic/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)

  #21 /home/harmonic/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php(201): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()

   #22 /home/harmonic/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_CategoryController->editAction()

   #23 /home/harmonic/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')

   #24 /home/harmonic/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))

    #25 /home/harmonic/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()

    #26 /home/harmonic/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)

    #27 /home/harmonic/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')

    #28 {main}";s:3:"url";s:84:"/index.php/murcielago13/catalog_category/index/key/3728137de42712df515ed0ee8fad43a4/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Comment: prima extension disable then check, this extension is conflict with existing functionality.

Comment: How do i find it? I have checked, I have checked, no Prima extension is installed on this installation.

Comment: You can check extension list at **System >> Configuration >> advanced** You can also disabled extension at here. You can find related to word extension any try to disabled it and check it again. Which extension you have installed related to category ?

Comment: Yes. I have checked there. There is no extension related to the category installed.

Comment: This is the list from disable module output page.............Cm_RedisSession
MagePsycho_Xmllinks
Magestore_Affiliateplus
Magestore_Affiliatepluslevel
Magestore_Affiliatepluspayment
Magestore_Affiliateplusprogram
Magestore_Affiliateplusstatistic
Magestore_Affiliatepluswidget
Magestore_Magenotification
Magestore_Onestepcheckout
Magestore_PaypalBNCode
Nwdthemes_All
Nwdthemes_Productslider
Phoenix_Moneybookers
SiteClue_Deleteorder
Sm_BasicProducts
Sm_Cartpro
Sm_DynamicSlideshow
Sm_Macy
Sm_Megamenu
Sm_Slider
VES_Core
VES_FuturePay
ZealousWeb_GTranslator

Comment: Can you give screenshot of this ?

Comment: I hv taken screenshot of modules and uploaded it on imgur..

<img src="http://i.imgur.com/94nr1wd.png" >
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/qbT25zY.png" />
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/yzxkDQ9.png" />
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/EymQvq1.png" />
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/iijG4A2.png" />